# 16.04 update disables previous working printer

Tags: 16.04

Brother Hl-2142 still works in 14.04 and has worked on all previous 16.04 updates.

16.04 May 2018 update includes 4.4.0.127 packages

In Printer Properties 'HL2142' /Settings/Printer State is "Stopped - Backend /usb/lib/cups/backend/usb  does not exist"

How can I solve this problem?

Aug 2018 Situation has changed.  Reload of cups and Printer State now shows Sending data but printer produces blank sheets.  Printer OK in Windows.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the printer driver (Brother proprietary or CUPS)?

Comment: 16.04 system error related to cups-pk-helper-mechanism and cups-pkhelper 0.2.5-2ubuntu2 have been reported  Re-installs have failed.